# How to convert EventCallback<T> to EventCallback<bool>

Tags: c#, events, blazor

Blazor has a generic class named EventCallback

How can I cast a

```
protected EventCallback<T> ValueChanged { get; set; }
```

to

```
EventCallback<bool> BoolChanged
   {
     get
     {
       if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
         return ValueChanged; //<== Error needs cast some how?
     }
   }
```

Comment: Hi Steve, could you give a bit more details on what you're doing? Normally you would just call ValueChanged.Invoke(newValue), you're obviously trying something a bit different here :)

Comment: Can you post the surrounding class/component?  It's not clear what you are trying to do here. Where do you want to put that `EventCallback<T> ValueChanged { get; set; }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Levi Broderick via Twitter for the answer.

```
protected EventCallback<bool> BoolChanged => (EventCallback<bool>)(object)ValueChanged;
```

He states: Bouncing the cast through object is basically a C# idiom for "I know the compiler can't reason about this at compile time, but try it anyway at runtime and I accept that an exception might occur."

Answer (score 2):

@Steven,can the following code represent and clarify your question ?

suppose I've the following components

```
@*Parent.razor*@

@page "/Parent"

<div>
    <Child Data="@Data" ValueChanged="@ValueChanged">
    </Child>
</div>

@functions {
    List<Item> Data = new List<Item>();

    private void ValueChanged(Item item)
    {        
    }
}


    @*Child.razor*@

@typeparam TData

<div>
    @foreach (var item in Data)
    {
        <button onclick="@(() => ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(item))"></button>
    }
</div>

@functions {
    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<TData> Data { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    protected EventCallback<TData> ValueChanged { get; set; }
}




  // Item.cs
public class Item
{
     public Item()
     {

     }
}
```

> As you can see I've two components, and am using generics(typeparam)
>   with EventCallback... Now, I want to define EventCallback property
>   with a get accessor that checks if the type of TData is bool, and if
>   it does, coverts the ValueChanged delegate to EventCallback

```
EventCallback<bool> BoolChanged { 
    get 
    { 
       if (typeof(TData) == typeof(bool)) return ValueChanged; // Needs conversion, but how
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Yes Issac that is basically the issue,  See my answer from Levi for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever try

```
(EventCallback<bool>)ValueChanged;
```

Ensure that type of `ValueChanged` in that case is `EventCallback<bool>`.

Comment: Error CS0030 Cannot convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<T>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<bool>'